# Python Bokeh Version 0.13.0 RangeTool import error

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, importerror

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

dates = np.array(AAPL['date'], dtype=np.datetime64)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=dates, close=AAPL['adj_close']))

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800, tools="", toolbar_location=None,
       x_axis_type="datetime", x_range=(dates[1500], dates[2500]))

p.line('date', 'close', source=source)
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'

select = figure(plot_height=150, plot_width=800, y_range=p.y_range,
            x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type=None,
            tools="", toolbar_location=None)
range_rool = RangeTool(x_range=p.x_range)
range_rool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_rool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.line('date', 'close', source=source)
select.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_rool)
select.toolbar.active_multi = range_rool

show(column(p, select))
```

Using Python 3.6, Bokeh 0.13.0, Juptyer 5.5.0

Tried Running this code, however it is giving me "ImportError: cannot import name 'RangeTool' "

How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot import `RangeTool` then you 100% have some kind of installation problem. A common thing is to have installed Bokeh 0.13.0 in a different Python environment than the one you are currently running Python from (perhaps inadvertently). This is *especially* common in conjunction with the notebook. I have seen very many people install Bokeh in a different environment than the notebook, so that when they run the notebook, of course it sees some other, older Bokeh version. You can always execute

```
print(bokeh.__version__)
```

to confirm that you are actually using the version you think you are using. Otherwise, if that reports `0.13.0` then the install was botched somehow. Blow away everything Bokeh related in `site-packages` and reinstall.

Comment: Thank You so much! I was able to fix this by a simple uninstall and install.